# populate dropdown list with years in SQL including 'NA'

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to have a dropdown list with 100 years going back from 2015. I have found the SQL code to do that, but I would like to incorporate the characters 'NA' for records that do not have a year. I would prefer not to create a table; I would like it to be dynamic.

SQL below (I found this on this website, btw)

```
DECLARE @yearStart int,@yearEnd int
SET @yearStart=1915
SET @yearEnd=2015;

WITH mycte AS(SELECT @yearStart as myYear 
UNION ALL
SELECT myYear+1 FROM mycte WHERE myYear<@yearEnd)

SELECT * FROM mycte
```

Comment: So you just want 'NA' in the drop down along with the last 100 years?

Comment: Why do you need to execute a select statement to populate a drop down list with the last 100 year numbers? Why do you need to ask it to the database?

Comment: Don't execute a select statement for it, just use Enumerable.Range and Enumberable.Concat.

Comment: This will be used for birth years in a third party software. Companies don't have birthdates so I need to exclude them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that adding the 'NA' shouldn't be done in SQL, but if you want to, then just [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) it on;

```
DECLARE @yearStart int,@yearEnd int
SET @yearStart=1915
SET @yearEnd=2015;

WITH mycte AS(SELECT @yearStart as myYear 
UNION ALL
SELECT myYear+1 FROM mycte WHERE myYear<@yearEnd)

SELECT 'NA' as MyYear
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(myYear AS VARCHAR(4)) FROM mycte
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @yearStart int,@yearEnd int

```
SET @yearStart=1915

SET @yearEnd=2015;

WITH mycte AS(SELECT @yearStart as myYear 

UNION ALL

SELECT myYear+1 FROM mycte WHERE myYear<@yearEnd)


SELECT CAST(myYear as VARCHAR(4)) FROM mycte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NA'
```

You can add an UNION ALL, if it has to be handled in SQL but in my opinion you should be handling this in front end.

Comment: Thank you Sourav_Agasti, but I get the message 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int'. Which is what I got originally when I did a Union. I have the answer now. thanks again